# Show that two combinations of two vectors in two dimensional space takes 7 multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I was reading the book Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Gilbert Strong(4th edition page-15) and in the first chapter came across the line

> Two combinations of two vectors in two dimensional space would seem to take 8 multiplications, but they can be done in 7.
> Can someone explain this following sentence?,

1. What does it mean by the word "combination" and how it normally take 8 multiplications.
2. How we can reduce it to 7?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tniJa.jpg)

Comment: By “combination” it means “linear combination”. Multiplying two $2\times2$ matrices can be viewed as computing two linear combinations of two vectors.